# MS AppSource SaaS Web App - restrict access for multi tenant web app

Tags: azure, office365, publish, multi-tenant, appsource

I develop multi tenant web app.

App is cofigured to support Accounts in any organizational directory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-modify-supported-accounts).

I plan to register App in AppSource marketplace "Web App" category (https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/?product=web-apps).

App must support "Free Trial" publishing option (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/determine-your-listing-type).

How to restrict access to my app only for trial organizations and organizations that bought a license?

How to check license? Or maybe Azure will not grant users access tokens for app if they have no license?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/offer-creation-checklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«There are loosely 2 kinds of SaaS Apps that we support today - Listing and Sell Through Microsoft. Listing is when all you want to do is to list your SaaS offer on Microsoft marketplaces and all the customer interaction, provisioning, commerce etc is handled by you and your SaaS experiences. Sell Through Microsoft is what allows you to enable your SaaS offer trasanctable via Microsoft marketplaces.»
https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Microsoft-AppSource-and-Azure/SaaS-Onboarding-Walkthrough-or-End-to-End-Document-for/m-p/7731/highlight/true#M123

If you want (as me) to sell through Microsoft, here is API
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/pc-saas-fulfillment-api-v2